# The process won't wait?

Tags: delphi, cmd, createprocess, delphi-10.3-rio

the code i use is as below:

```
 begin
     saSecurity.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
     saSecurity.bInheritHandle := True;
     saSecurity.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
     FillChar(suiStartup, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
     suiStartup.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
     suiStartup.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
     suiStartup.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

     ccOk:=CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ExecutableFirst+' '+CommandsFirst),@saSecurity,@saSecurity, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, suiStartup, piProcess);

      if ccOk then
       begin
         CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ExecutableSecond + ' ' + CommandsSecond), @saSecurity,@saSecurity, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, suiStartup, piProcess);
           try
            repeat                 Running:=MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(2,piProcess.hProcess,True,100,QS_ALLINPUT);
             Application.ProcessMessages;
             until Running <> WAIT_TIMEOUT
           finally
            CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
            if (Running=WAIT_OBJECT_0) then BidsConversion; //run this when both process has finished
           end;
       end else    
       begin
       raise.Exception(GetLastError.toString);
        Exit
       end;
 end;
```

The Code working but sometimes it is firing `BidsConversion` however the First Process is still not completed hence it Exception raised.

Why the app is not waiting for both processes to finish then fire the procedure ?

Comment: Go back to WaitForSingleObject. Wait for one process. Then the other. Indeed start by trying to wait for just one process at a time without blocking the UI. Don't try to run before you can walk.

Comment: Please don't ask a new question by removing the old one and replacing with new code.

Comment: You are currently unable execute a single process, and wait for it without blocking the UI of the parent. Trying to write the code to do so for two processes before you have succeeded with one is not going to be productive. Again. Do not try to run before you can walk. View this entire problem as a series of learning stepping stones. This is how people learn.

Comment: It is frustrating to keep telling you the same thing and you keep making the same mistakes. For instance, the pipes. This is now the fourth time I've told you that it is wrong to connect both ends of a single pipe to the standard input and standard output of a single process. Think about it. Does a process really want to encounter its own output when it reads its input? The reason this isn't working for you is that you haven't mastered the basics yet. You need to stop trying to solve your ultimate goal and first learn the skills that will ultimately be required. This takes time.

Answer (score 3):

You are not checking the return value of the 2nd `CreateProcess()` to see if it failed, but more importantly you are completely misusing `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`:

- you are not passing *both* process handles to `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` even though you are setting its `nCount` parameter to 2.
- you are calling `ProcessMessages()` unconditionally, even when `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` does not tell you that messages are waiting to be processed.
- your loop's `until` clause is checking for the wrong termination value, so your loop will break prematurely on ANY condition that is not a timeout, eg: when either process finishes, or when a message is pending in the queue.
- there is an important caveat with setting the `bWaitAll` parameter to True that you need to be aware of - see [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects is a very tricky API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2004/06/02/things-you-shouldnt-do-part-4-msgwaitformultipleobjects-is-a-very-tricky-api/) on MSDN for details about that.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
var
  ...
  arrHandles: array[0..1] of THandle;
  numHandles, i: Integer;
begin
  ...

  ccOk := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ExecutableFirst + ' ' + CommandsFirst), @saSecurity, @saSecurity, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, suiStartup, piProcess);
  if not ccOk then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
  arrHandles[0] := piProcess.hProcess;
  numHandles := 1;

  try
    ccOk := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ExecutableSecond + ' ' + CommandsSecond), @saSecurity, @saSecurity, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, suiStartup, piProcess);
    if not ccOk then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
    arrHandles[1] := piProcess.hProcess;
    numHandles := 2;

    // there is a caveat when setting bWaitAll=True that the wait will not be
    // completely satisfied until both handles are signaled AND the calling thread
    // receives an input event!  That last caveat is not desirable, so setting
    // bWaitAll=False instead to avoid that so the loop can break immediately when
    // both handles are signaled...
    repeat
      Running := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(numHandles, arrHandles, False, INFINTE, QS_ALLINPUT);
      if {(Running >= WAIT_OBJECT_0) and} (Running < (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + DWORD(numHandles))) then
      begin
        i := Integer(Running - WAIT_OBJECT_0);
        CloseHandle(arrHandles[i]);
        if i = 0 then arrHandles[0] := arrHandles[1];
        Dec(numHandles);
      end
      else if Running = (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + DWORD(numHandles)) then begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      end
      else if Running = WAIT_FAILED then begin
        RaiseLastOSError;
      end;
    until numHandles = 0;
  except
    for i := 0 to numHandles-1 do begin
      TerminateProcess(arrHandles[i], 0);
      CloseHandle(arrHandles[i]);
    end;
    raise;
  end;

  BidsConversion; //run this when both processes have finished without error

  ...
end;
```

That being said, consider doing the wait asynchronously in a separate worker thread so you are not blocking the main UI thread anymore.  You can create your own thread that calls `WaitForMultipleObjects()` (not `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` since you would not need to wait on the message queue anymore), or you can use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` on each process handle individually. Either way, let the worker thread(s) notify the main UI thread when waiting is finished, and just don't call `BidsConversion()` until you have received notification that both processes have finished.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. There are Warnings `Comparison always evaluates to True` and  `Comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands` at `if (Running>=..) and (Running = ..)` and currently i am not using different thread and the UI is still not blocking so is it really need for putting it in .execute class (or maybe i am missing something) ?  and i tried to add pipe to read error messages from the cmdline and updated the code in main question please see if it's good.

Comment: @webs1893 I updated my answer to address the warnings. But as for your pipe usage, it is not even close to being correct. There are plenty of answers on StackOverflow regarding using pipes for Stdin/Stdout redirection. But performing reads only when window messages are received is not ideal. If you use a named pipe instead, you can use overlapped I/O for the reading, and include the overlapped event handle in the handle array that you wait on so you can read when you are notified to read. And you should use 2 pipes and 2 buffers, one set per process, so you don't mix outputs in the same buffer